# What's wrong with this sql syntax (adding columns)

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
ALTER table counties add public_schools DECIMAL(5,4), public_trans DECIMAL(6,5);
```

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECIMAL(6,5)' at line 1*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to repeat `add`:

```
ALTER table counties
    add public_schools DECIMAL(5, 4),
    add public_trans DECIMAL(6, 5);
```